# Choosing test config and settings in python flask project when running py.test

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

How to control which *_settings.py or config/*.py is loaded when starting py.test? I have some defaults set in **init**.py and some values in development.py. I have tried to load test values from conftest.py but conftest gets executed after the other 2 are loaded. I am specifically looking to change the db being used in development, test and production modes. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is configuration management in flask. Take a look at this document: [flask config management](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/)

This SO question could help you too: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603240/flask-how-to-manage-different-environment-databases)

Basically, depending on your environment (devel / production / test) you change parameter specifying with which settings your app should start. Using system environment variables is one of the option.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS')
```

Then, on your devel machine, just set env variable

```
export YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS="/path/to/settings.conf"
```

and run the application.

On production environment, do the same thing, just change value to `/path/to/production/settings.conf`