# Non existing path when setting up Flask to have separated configurations for each environment

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, python-import

I have separated configs for each environment and one single app, the
directory tree looks like:

```
myapp
├── __init__.py         # empty
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py     # empty
│   ├── development.py
│   ├── default.py
│   └── production.py
├── instance
│   └── config.py
└── myapp
   ├── __init__.py
   └── myapp.py
```

### Code

The relevant code, `myapp/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_object('config.default')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
app.config.from_envvar('APP_CONFIG_FILE')
```

`myapp/myapp.py`:

```
from myapp import app
# ...
```

### Commands

Then I set the variables:

```
$export FLASK_APP=myapp.py
```

And try to run the development server from the project root:

```
$ flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: The file/path provided (myapp.py) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

And from the project `myapp` folder:

```
$ cd myapp
$ flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: The file/path provided (myapp.myapp.myapp) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

With another `FLASK_APP` variable:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=myapp/myapp.py
# in project root
$ flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: The file/path provided (myapp.myapp.myapp) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
# moving to project/myapp
$ cd myapp
$ flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: The file/path provided (myapp/myapp.py) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

#### Other test without success

```
$ python -c 'import myapp; print(myapp)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/myapp/myapp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    app.config.from_envvar('APP_CONFIG_FILE')
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/config.py", line 108, in from_envvar
    variable_name)
RuntimeError: The environment variable 'APP_CONFIG_FILE' is not set and as such configuration could not be loaded.  Set this variable and make it point to a configuration file

$ export APP_CONFIG_FILE="/home/user/myapp/config/development.py"
$ python -c 'import myapp; print(myapp)'<module 'myapp' from '/home/user/myapp/myapp/__init__.py'>
$ flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Error: The file/path provided (myapp.myapp) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

### Notes:

- I am not using the `PYTHON_PATH` variable, it is empty
- I have already seen other related questions ([Flask: How to manage different environment databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15603240/1165509)) but my problem is the (relatevely new) *flask* command
- Using Python 3.5.2+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a while but I finally found it:

1. Flask doesn't like projects with `__init__.py` at root level, delete **`myapp/__init__.py`**. This is the one located at the root folder:

   ```
   myapp
   ├── __init__.py     <--- DELETE
   ...
   └── myapp
       ├── __init__.py  <--- keep
       └── myapp.py
   ```
2. Use `$ export FLASK_APP=myapp/myapp.py`
3. The environment variable specifying the configuration **should be the absolut path** to it: `export APP_CONFIG_FILE="/home/user/myapp/config/development.py"`

Now everything works \o/

```
$ flask run
* Serving Flask app "myapp.myapp"
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

$ flask shell
Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160927] on linux
App: myapp
Instance: /home/user/myapp/instance
>>>
```

Comment: I have exact same structure of my project, but I am still getting same error.

Comment: @vishal do you have a public repo?

Comment: @marcaunuy, just created one, https://github.com/vishalmelmatti/flasktest

Comment: @vishal I had a running instance adding `__init__.py` to each subfolder and use `export FLASK_APP=Spy/Spy.py`, comment each import from Spy.py and start trying to debug it uncommenting one by one. In my case I ended up using `PYTHONPATH`, you can have a look at https://github.com/marcanuy/notificamesta

Comment: I am already doing export FLASK_APP=Spy/Spy.py. Will tryout other steps. Thanks

Comment: It worked form me. Just to mention that you should execute `flash run` in the root of your project instead of myapp/myapp by mistake

Comment: @marcanuy so thankful to have found this post - I had the same exact issue with __init__.y sitting at root level. Obvious in retrospect, less so when you are looking for it.